# Wrap Typescript definition file in module automatically

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am most probably missing some tsconfig option here.

What Im doing is pretty simple:

I am creating an npm module, for example:

```
export class HelloWorld {
    constructor(public greeting: string){}
}
```

with my tsconfig being:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "../js"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

When my declaration is automatically created it looks like this:

```
export declare class HelloWorld {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(greeting: string);
}
```

But that doesnt work well when actually installing the npm package in other projects. When I import the package I have to use:

```
import hello = require("hello-world/js/index");
```

(for example)

I found out that when I wrap the declaration file in module `declare module "hello-world" {...}` Then I can import it as desired by `import hello = require("hello-world");`

Wrapping the generated definition file manually is not an option as it rewrites itself all the time, is there any option that would take name of the package from `package.json` and automatically wrap the definition in that module?

Comment: did you try 'export default class HelloWorld'?

Comment: @baryo yes doesnt make any difference

Comment: could you please post your package.json ?

Comment: Have a look at this article which explains where does typescript look for typings,etc:  http://ivanz.com/2016/06/07/how-does-typescript-discover-type-declarations-definitions-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `typings` property specified in `package.json`...

```
{
    "name": "hello-world",
    "typings": "hello-world.d.ts",
    ...etc...
}
```

...or change your definition file to be named `index.d.ts`.

Then after installing the package with these changes, the compiler will be able to resolve it when you write:

```
import hello = require("hello-world");
```

[More details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html)

Comment: `import {HelloWorld} from 'hello-world'; new HelloWorld("greeting here");` instead of require ?

Comment: @IvanZlatev I always use es6 modules, but I just used require because they used it as well. My memory of exactly how require works is slowly fading to be honest :)